# Why is this while loop looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So i'm making a web app for my studies, it basically uses a combination of Twitter's streaming api and Google Maps to display the Lat Lng values.

Y is an element which states the number of tweets which have been received,  ( checks length of an array) and X is another which has it's text content incremented by 1 every second.

- I just put some random values for the time for it to take, I would use a more logical scale ( every 60 secs or something).

I wanted to log this information every minute, to make a graph but i've made an infinite loop somehow and i'm not quite sure how.

Here's the code:

```
function saveinfo(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('timer')[0].textContent;
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0].textContent;
while (x != "510"){
    if(x = "5"){
        console.log(y);

    }
    else if (x = "200") {
        console.log(y);

    }
    else if (x = "300"){
        console.log(y);

    }
    else if (x = "400"){
        console.log(y);

    }
    else if (x = "500"){
        console.log(y);
        x = "510"
    }
}
};
```

Comment: `x = "200"` should be `x === "200"` etc for a start. You want to check if they're equal, not assign 200 to x.

Comment: if x is not '500', it doesn't get changed

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I should've noticed that.

Comment: @ailerifren x is an element which is increased by 1 every second on my page, at some point it would reach 510.

Answer (score 3):

When your `if` statements are evaluated, you're setting `x`:

```
if(x = "5"){
```

This means that `x` will never equal `"510"`, and your loop will go on forever.

To fix this, you should do something like `if(x === '5')`

Comment: Consider community wiki for this answer.

Comment: Yep, simple mistake really. However it doesn't actually solve the issue it seems ( the script doesn't respond when I load the page). I think @Luaan is correct about x and y being local, I just assumed if the element's text content changed the variable would also change.

If that's the case I suppose I have to access the elements text content for each iteration? If JS is single threaded, then this is impossible?

Comment: cause now you have two problems: `"5" === 5 // false` String ain't a Number and 2nd. unless `x` is exactly `500` the loop never changes `x` and therefore the condition for the loop is always true -> infinite loop. **I think you totally misunderstand the `while`-keyword.**

Answer (score 0):

Three main reasons:

- `x` is a local variable, not a reference to the content in the element. When the content changes, the value in `x` stays the same.
- `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator. You need to use `==` (or better, `===`) for comparison. Since `x = "5"` evaluates to `true`, you will never get past the first `if`.
- Your loop prevents the UI from updating anyway, because JavaScript is by default single-threaded. Even if you *did* read the value in the timer all the time rather than reading the local, it would still never change.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else statements aren't working.
 You put in `if(x = "200")` instead of `if( x == "200")`.
 In if/else statements, `if(x=1)`doesn't work.
 `if(x==1)` or `if(x=="1")` always work.
 `if(x==="1")` works only if x is a string that says "1".
 `if(x===1)` only works if x is a number.

All you need to do is change the `if(x="number")` into `if(x=="number")`