# Javascript function going into a loop

Tags: javascript

I have this below function in my project:-

```
function RowSelection() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tbl_Audit");
  if (table != null) {
    for (var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[x].cells.length; j++) {
        if (j = 4) {
          alert("condition passed " + j)
          table.rows[x].cells[j].onclick = function() {
            tableText(this);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when this function is triggered it goes into a never ending loop. Can anybody please help me identify what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Console log the table.rows.length; What's the count ? And also table.rows[x].cells.length whats the count ?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460244/why-is-this-while-loop-looping-infinitely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if (j=4)` to `if (j===4)`.

`=` is an assignment, which isn't a syntax error so the code runs, but it changes the value of `j` to `4`, so (assuming 4 is less than the number of cells) your loop condition will always be true.

Comment: Hmm, that's right. But can that cause never ending loop ?

Comment: @Nandan - Sure, because `j` is the inner loop's counter.

Comment: Okay, But what I thought was, for every iteration, the if block should be executed right? So if the table.rows[x].cells.length value is 1000 (just example) it should show alert for 1000*outer loop count. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Nandan - At the end of every iteration of the inner loop, `j` will be incremented by the `j++` of the `for`, but then the `if (j=4)` will change `j` back to `4`. So every time (after the first) that the inner loop condition is evaluated `j` will be `5`. If that is less than `table.rows[x].cells.length` then the inner loop condition will always be true.